# When I am tryibg to change Mac Address through python code this message occurred "a password is required"

Tags: python, macos

When I am trying to run this below code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", "eth0", "down"])
subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", "eth0", "hw", "ether", "00:11:22:33:44:55"])
subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", "eth0", "up"])
```

The error mentioned below occurred:

> sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
>
> sudo: a password is required

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run the command `sudo`. This command requires the user to insert a password. Since you are running it from a script, it cannot receive the password.
You should instead run the command without `sudo` and run the entire python script with `sudo`